# "return value type does not match the function type" and other VS compile errors

Tags: c++

I started to learn C++ a few days ago and now I'm trying to make my first program ever, a "phone-book" app. The name of the people I know will appear, I will enter the name of the person I need the number and their number will appear.

But now I am debugging for a while and I still don't get what's wrong with my code! I'm pretty sure it's obvious though, I'm just too new to get it.

```
    #include <stdafx.h> // Visual Studio users need to uncomment this line
    #include <iostream>

    int nameAppears()
 {
    std::cout << "Alex" <<    std::endl;
    std::cout << "Andre" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Guy" <<   std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-ma" <<        std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-pa" <<        std::endl;
    std::cout << "Jérémy" <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "Manon" <<   std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nathalie" <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stéphanie" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Oliver" << std::endl;
}


int enterName()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the name you wish to obtain the number:";
    int name;
    std::cin >> name;
    return name;
}


int link(name)
{
    if (name == "Alex")
        return "586 6532";
    if (name == "Andre")
        return "569 8522";
    if (name == "Guy")
        return "850 6589";
    if (name == "Grand-ma")
        return "482 4875";
    if (name == "Grand-pa")
        return "453 9963";
    if (name == "Jérémy")
        return "654 3828";
    if (name == "Manon")
        return "965 4541";
    if (name == "Nathalie")
        return "770 6916";
    if (name == "Stéphanie")
        return "546 5482 ";
    if (name == "Oliver")
        return "246 5554";
}


int printNumber (int number)
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    //Make all the names appear
    nameAppears();

    //Get User's input
    int name = enterName();

    //Link Name to number
    int number = link(name);

    //Print the desired number
    printNumber(number);
}
```

Here is a list of all the errors I got while compiling this on Visual Studio 2013:

- "cannot open source file "stdafx.h""
- "identifier "name" is undefined" (2 times in a row)
- "return value type does not match the function type" (10 times in a row)
- ""name": undeclared identifier"
- ""link: function-style initializer appears to be a function definition"
- "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments"

Comment: I suspect you don't have precompiled headers enabled in your project. Either enable it and add a stdafx.h file to your project or comment out the <stdafx.h> include. Check your function signatures--you're missing something rather important on one. You're mixing up c-style strings and integers, too.

Comment: All your functions have a return type of int, yet none of them return anything

Comment: Stop *just trying*.

Comment: Also, you *really* need a good C++ book you have a lot of basic mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to start?

## 1. Why a name should be a number?

In your function:

```
int enterName()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the name you wish to obtain the number:";
    int name;
    std::cin >> name;
    return name;
}
```

The user is supposed to insert a *name* but the type of a `name` variable has been declared as `int` (which is a type for a *integer* number). My question now is: *why the name of a person should be codified as a number?*

### How to solve this?

Simply using a [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) type.

```
#include <string>  // You have to include this header to use string object

// ...

std::string enterName()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the name you wish to obtain the number:";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    return name;
}
```

*Note: there are many considerations about how to get a string from the standard input, but I'm not your c++ teacher, and in your case I think that argument is very far from your skills now.*

## 2. C++ is statically type language (*more or less*).

Another problem is here:

```
int link(name)
{
  // do something ...
}
```

In your declaration function `name` has not type. This is an error! A variable must to have a type as argument.

Moreover your body function returns a "*string*" type:

```
return "965 4541";  // return a const char[]
```

So why you've declared your function returns a `int` type?

### Correct form:

```
std::string link(const std::string& name)  // declaration signature
```

## 3. And again...

Even in this function the type are wrong:

```
int printNumber (int number)
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
}
```

It should be:

```
void printNumber (const std::string& number)
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
}
```

`void` as return type because your function does return nothing.

## Final Conclusions

I see a lack in your baseline skills about the language. I suggest you to study a good C++ book, and start coding from that.

Answer (score 0):

1. "identifier "name" is undefined" you are not declaring the variable name inside the function link, the correct is `int main (string name)`, you need that `string`.
2. "return value type does not match the function type" using as example the function `int link(string name)`, if you want to return the phone number or you return it like 8506589 (no spaces) or you change the return type to string so it consider a string and accept things like - or space.

3- No need for stdafx header, erase this line and google it for understanding more about it.

4- You declared name as an int, you should have declared as a string.

Dude, your code have so many problems, you should consider going to some youtube videos is you are trying to learn by yourself and watch some videos for c programming first, try thenewboston videos... I helped with just few of your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `using namespace std` and `string name` you are using an int. Integers are only for numbers not strings. `string name;  cin >> name`